How does Ubuntu 22.04+ set cpu governor?
I have a heavily customized over the years Ubuntu installation and I see that my CPU governor on 22.04 is performance.
However it seems like on modern AMD machines (other systems I have) the default is schedutil.
I'm having a hard time finding what/where is setting it to schedutil or equally un-setting that to obtain performance instead.
I am not setting cpufreq.default_governor kernel parameter on boot and don't have cpufrequtils installed, I have not created systemd services to override it, but I might have removed some packages (I do not have ubuntu-desktop for many years for example).

I had Xanmod kernel installed and it is compiled with CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_PERFORMANCE=y instead of CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_SCHEDUTIL=y in the official Ubuntu kernel.
